# Нарисовать круговую диаграмму

Tags: gdi, winforms, .net, c++

Необходимо нарисовать круговую диаграмму. 
Managed C++.
Никогда прежде не рисовал на C++. Нашел функцию arc(), но она рисует только полый круг, который можно заполнить цветом. Нашел функцию pie(), но она только кусок "вырезает".

Подскажите, куда глядеть. И, хотя бы, малюсенький примерчик. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 1):

*"Общим видом овладели, теперь подробности не надо бы упускать" М.Жванецкий.*

Прочтите, пожалуйста, повнимательнее описание функции arc(....). Там в  скобках много всего.

Comment: Не разобрался и не понял. Ни одного примера нормального найти не могу.